# Passing variables to SCHTASKS in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, printing

I want to achieve that an authenticated domain user is able to pause or resume a print queue on a remote windows print server. The available role "manage printer" assigns too much control of the printer settings to the user, which is unwanted.

So I setup a script with pause print queue command running on client machine as scheduled task (the Name of scheduled task is "Pause Printer" and runs under a different user account with appropiate rights to control the queue on the remote print server):

`Invoke-Command -ComputerName $SrvName -ScriptBlock{(get-wmiobject win32_printer -filter "Name='$using:prName'").pause()}`

BTW: To make this work under WS2016, I had to modify the rights assignment for the scheduled task so that authenticated users can see and execute the scheduled task.

Now the user can issue this scheduled task by running this command on the client:

`` Start-Process -FilePath "schtasks" -ArgumentList "/run /TN:`"Pause Printer`"" -Wait -PassThru ``

That works ok so far.
Currently I have the values for print server and printer name hardcoded in both scripts.
To make these scripts available for common use, I'd like to pass the print servers name and printer name with variables as params, but I do not see any choice to pass these variables from the client script to the Scheduled task.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: It's not logical that this would be supported. A _scheduled_ task needs to know its arguments in advance of course, because it may run without a user being around (because it is _scheduled_)! That's why it's not supported. What you could do instead is writing a file and then starting the task.

Comment: @CherryDT: I agree and the file option was in my head, too. The whole solution is a workaround, because IMHO the granularity of user roles for windows printing isn't good enough.

Comment: If the operating system of your print server is Windows Server 2012 or above, you should prefer `Get-CimInstance` rather than `Get-WmiObject`